# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql

I have renamed my database in phpMyAdmin but it makes some problems. When I tried to rename it to its first name, it asked first if I want to rename it and drop my database.

When I press OK, it give me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near qetary2015-02-21.gps_poss

The SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE qetary2015-02-21.gps_poss
```

How can I fix it please?

Comment: And the SQL query that you used?

Comment: very sorry.. i have edited it now

Comment: Using ticks `\`` around `qetary2015-02-21` it figures you want to do math.

Comment: That's half your `ALTER TABLE` (and what is wrong with it is now clear) but presumably there's more to your statement than that?

Comment: no , its only this statement in my phpmyadmin site 

and it is the full error 


**Error
SQL query:


ALTER TABLE 'qetary20150221'.gps_possition


MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''qetary20150221'.gps_possition' at line 1 **

Comment: You say you renamed your database then you are altering a table with an invalid command against a table which you also then say doesn't exist - what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: yes ... i renamed my DB from "qetary " to "qetary2015-02-21" as a try 
and now it refused
I apologize for these errors...but i am new in mysql and phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

At a guess:

```
ALTER TABLE `qetary2015-02-21`.gps_poss
```

Wrap the database name in backticks, else the `-` character might be misinterpreted as a minus sign.... though I hope there's slightly more to your SQL query than that snippet

Comment: mmmmm... i want to say some thing there isn't atalbe called qetary2015-02-21
and i tried to put the ' but the error still found

Comment: i think you are right 
that the error in this sign "-"
but how i solve it?

Comment: I didn't say there was a table called `qetary2015-02-21`, I said a database named `qetary2015-02-21`..... the table name is `gps_poss` (based on the snippet of query you showed).... and the solution isn't to wrap it in quotes (`'`) but to wrap it in backticks (`\``)

Comment: yes ...its OK now that error have solved finally...but can i ask why it created new DB with the new name and the DB i wanted to rename remain the same

Comment: You can ask why, but I can't answer because I don't know exactly what you did... but clearly it wasn't what you thought

Comment: its OK ... and thank you very mutch
but is there any other way to rename the DB i want